# how do I guard against "foreach: No match"?

Tags: shell, csh, tcsh

I've got a shell script that looks like this:

```
foreach dir (i686.* amd64.*)
  # commands
end
```

The problem with this script is that if there are no directories matching those names then I get the following error:

```
"foreach: No match."
```

What's an elegant way to guard against this error?

Comment: @devnull `C-shell` or `tcsh`

Comment: @iamauser tcsh I think

Comment: One elegant way is to [not use csh](http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are two ways to handle this.

1. Set the shell's `nonomatch` variable.  This tells tcsh to leave a pattern unchanged if it doesn't match any files.  Thus:

   ```
   % set nonomatch=1
   % echo i686.* amd64.*
   i686.* amd64.*
   ```

   You will then need to make your commands handle the case of a non-matched pattern.
2. Pass an extra pattern that always matches.  Example:

   ```
   % echo i686.* amd64.* /dev/nul[l]
   /dev/null
   ```

   You will then need to make your commands ignore the file matched by the always-matched pattern.  This is probably easier than #1.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `grep` or `egrep` rather than a file matching pattern:

```
foreach dir ( `ls | egrep '^(i686\|amd64)\.'` )
    # commands
end
```

If no files match, the `ls | egrep ...` command simply won't produce any output, and the body of your loop won't execute.

Given the name `dir`, you might want to add a test that any matching file name is actually a directory.

An uglier alternative is to temporarily create a matching file:

```
tmp=i686.$$
mkdir $tmp
foreach dir (i686.* amd64.*)
    if ($dir != $tmp) then
        # commands
    endif
end
rm $tmp
```

I don't necessarily recommend this.

You might want to use a `:q` suffix or add double quotes if you need to worry about directory names containing funny characters.